# Regex for sorting through files in numbered folders using os.walk

Tags: python, regex

I'm using os.walk to crawl through a directory containing numbered folders, i.e. DOY100, DOY101, DOY102, etc. My goal is to return files within each numbered directory if they are within a defined upper/lower limit, i.e. return only files within folders DOY109 through DOY158, where 109 and 158 are user defined limits.

Here is a snipped of Python code I'm currently working with:

```
DOY_START = 109
DOY_END = 158

regex = re.compile('(file1_regex.txt)|file2_regex.txt')

rootdir = "C:/Users/Inputs/..."
output_dir = "C:/Users/Outputs/..."

exclude = set(['DOY100', 'DOY101', ... , 'DOY108', 'DOY159', ...])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
   
    for file in files:
        res = re.match(regex, file)

        if res:
            full_file_path = root + "/" + file
            copy2(full_file_path, output_dir)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How could I exclude all directories from my os.walk that fall outside of the user-defined range of DOY_START and DOY_END?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `DOY(?P<num>\d+)` to get only the suffix numbers of the folder. Then, check if the number lies within the desired range (`DOY_START` <= num <= `DOY_END`). Afterwards, use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to copy the files from the source to destination (using the argument from Python 3.8+ `dirs_exist_ok`, to avoid raising an exception in case dst or any missing parent directory already exists).

Input folder tree

```
Users
├───Inputs
│   ├───DOY100
│   │       sample_100.dat
│   ├───DOY101
│   │       sample_101.dat
│   ├───DOY102
│   │       sample_102.dat
... ...
... ...
│   ├───DOY197
│   │       sample_197.dat
│   ├───DOY198
│   │       sample_198.dat
│   └───DOY199
│           sample_199.dat
└───Outputs
```

```py
import re
import os
import shutil

DOY_START = 109
DOY_END = 158

regex = re.compile(r'DOY(?P<num>\d+)')

rootdir = "Users/Inputs/"
output_dir = "Users/Outputs/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=True):
    for d in dirs:
        match = regex.search(d)
        if match:
            if DOY_START <= int(match['num']) <= DOY_END:
                full_file_path = os.path.join(root, d)
                # New in version 3.8: The dirs_exist_ok parameter.
                shutil.copytree(full_file_path, output_dir, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Output folder tree

```
Users
├── Inputs
└── Outputs
    ├── sample_109.dat
    ├── sample_110.dat
    ├── ...
    ├── ...
    ├── sample_157.dat
    └── sample_158.dat
```